# launchFragment while testing showing error

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso, robolectric

Using this guide to test dialog https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/test
The bottom sample

```
with(launchFragment<MyDialogFragment>()) {
        onFragment { fragment -> // here error
            assertThat(fragment.dialog).isNotNull()
            assertThat(fragment.requireDialog().isShowing).isTrue()
            fragment.dismiss()
            fragment.parentFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()
            assertThat(fragment.dialog).isNull()
        }
    }
```

But here it shows error

```
 onFragment { fragment -> // error below
```

Type mismatch.
Required:
FragmentScenario.FragmentAction
Found:
(???) → Unit
Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly

Comment: What version of `fragment-testing` are you using? What version of Kotlin?

Comment: @ianhanniballake 1.3.2 fragment testing Kotlin 1.4.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys the solution was Kotlin version. So update Kotlin plugin in studio solves the issue

Comment: This didn't solve my issue, using `fragment-testing` 1.3.6 and Kotlin 1.5.20. Error is Type mismatch. Required: Nothing

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the kotlin version in module `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        kotlin_version = "1.5.31"
    }
}
```

My origin kotlin version is 1.3.x, and it happened with the same error.

Then I go to github for the guide and found out [that](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-words-app/blob/nav_test_solution/build.gradle).